# how can one column of a multicolumn primary key be used as a foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have a mapping table as such:

```
english.Phrases (PhraseId int, WordId int, Order int)
Primary Key Clustered (PhraseId, WordId)
```

And another table:

```
english.RelatedPhrases (RelatedPhraseId int, PhraseId int)
```

How do I setup a foreign key relationship between the 2 tables using `PhraseId`?

Edited to answer comment on which database:
I'm using Microsoft SQL 2008, hence, I changed the tag.

The mapping should be as follows; consider the following phrases:

```
1. "turn out to be", phraseId of 1
2. "grow to be", phraseId of 2
3. "turn into", phraseId of 3
4. "come to be", phraseId of 4
```

Each word has an entry in the following table:

```
english.Words (WordId int, Word varchar(20))
```

The english.Phrases table has the following entries for "turn out to be":

```
(1, @word1Id, 1) @word1Id = id of 'turn'
(1, @word2Id, 2) @word2Id = id of 'out'
(1, @word3Id, 3) @word3Id = id of 'to'
(1, @word4Id, 4) @word4Id = id of 'be'
```

Now, what I want from the english.RelatedPhrases table is to have the PhraseId of 1, which represents "turn out to be", to relate to the other phrases, say in this case, 2, 3, and 4; all 4 entries in RelatedPhrases having RelatedPhraseId = 1.

Comment: Normally you can't set a foreign key to anything except the (complete) primary key. What database are you using?

Comment: And what is that mapping exactly? That all PhraseAs no matter what the wordid are related to all PhraseBs? Rethink your schema

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson IIRC depending on the DB you can also point to a complete UNIQUE indexed

Comment: @Luis True, I was referring to the tag being only "SQL" and afaik that is not a standard SQL feature.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Phrase` table can have multiple rows with the same PhraseID, you should introduce a new table.  For example:

```
create table PhraseIds (
    PhraseId int primary key)

create table Phrase (
    PhraseId int foreign key references PhraseIds, 
    WordId int, 
    [Order] int,
    primary key (PhraseID, WordId))

create table RelatedPhrases (
    RelatedPhraseId int primary key, 
    PhraseId int foreign key references PhraseIds(PhraseID))
```

Comment: Though this does not answer the question, I have decided to go with this approach afterall, mainly because it allows me to persist summary data per phrase, such as, NumberOfWords & NumberOfCharacters, thereby saving me the cost of aggregating via joins.

Comment: A foreign key can only reference a unique set of columns.  This condition has no relation to the number of columns in the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if record exists in trigger.. 
just don't forget about performance.